# sendError with message oncePerRequestFilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter

Hello im using oncePerRequestFilter, and i need to use sendError function in it, but error message is not being sent... only code status...

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


    try {
        if (someCondition) {
            httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Your account is locked" );
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    return;
}
```

Is there way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it with adding

httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("Your account is locked");

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following to your application.properties:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

This would always include the error message along with the status code in your error responses.

Comment: Cannot resolve configuration property 'server.error.include-message'

Comment: Good advice. But missing important information: ```server.error.include-message: since version 2.3, Spring Boot hides the message field in the response to avoid leaking sensitive information; we can use this property with an always value to enable it```